# Why won't environment variables added to .profile show up in screen

Tags: command-line, bash, screen, environment-variables, .profile

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

I added

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dspies/workspace/hdf5-1.8.11-linux-shared/lib
```

to .profile

but when I log in and open terminal and put `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` there's nothing.

When I switch to ctrl-alt-F1 and log in, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
gives

```
/home/dspies/workspace/hdf5-1.8.11-linux-shared/lib
```

but then when I run `screen`, `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within screen is empty again

In what circumstances can I expect environment variables from .profile to be set? (interestingly, it seems any modifications to PATH made in .profile always show up)

EDIT: Sorry, I guess I didn't clarify what I really wanted to know which is:
How can I set an environment variable that I mean to be set anywhere (ie in screen, in terminal, when I log-in, and when I ssh in)?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: From within terminal, it's just "bash", in CTRL-ALT-F1, it's "-bash", and in screen, it's "/bin/bash".  Why?  What is $0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

I should set them in .pam_enviornment

See here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

I imagine this is one of the most common questions, I don't know why nobody gave me the proper answer when I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

From the Bash manual:

> When  bash  is  invoked  as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
>   exists and is readable.

That means if you have a `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` in your home folder, then bash won't read the contents of your `.profile`. Additionally, when not running in an interactive login shell, `.profile` won't be read either.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $0
```

will return the script name which is being executed, when this command is executed within a shell script. In a terminal, it will return the type of shell being used.

You are using `bash` shell. You need to add this line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dspies/workspace/hdf5-1.8.11-linux-shared/lib
```

to `~/.bash_profile` file.

**EDIT:**

You may find the different login profile scipt names for different shells, [here](http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/07/what-is-profile-file.html)

**EDIT2:**

Even I got two different responses when I executed `echo $0` on two different machines. On one machine, I got `bash` and on the other I got `-bash`. I asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686957/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-and-bash). This is what I got as the answer.

```
Processes with a - at the beginning of arg 0 have been run via login, or by exec -l in bash.
```

After reading that answer, I did `help exec` and that reads, `If the first argument is '-l', then place a dash in the zeroth arg passed to FILE, as login does`.